# How to return the two biggest items in an OCaml int list in the most efficient way?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to Caml and don't always understand everything I'm doing.
In a homework I am asked to write a function which, given `l` a list of n integers and `max` a function which returns the biggest integer of two, returns the two biggest items in l, calling the `max` function at most 2n-3 times. I have already made a `max_in_list` function which returns the biggest, if this can be useful:

```
let max a1 a2 = if a1>a2 then a1 else a2;;

let rec max_in_list l = match l with
    | [] -> 0
    | [a] -> a
    | a::q -> max a (max_in_list q)
;;
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Well right away, a empty list shouldn't return 0 if the function returns the two largest integers.

Comment: `max_in_list` is supposed to return the one largest, and logically this shouldn't operate on an empty list unless the list is empty to begin with, I only added this so that it returns something if the input is an empty list. Implied, the input list in the function that would return the two biggest should have 2 items at least anyway.

Comment: Are you allowed to consider Option types?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Have you put any thought yourself into how to solve this? Have you attempted to write any code? Can you show us? Can you explain more specifically what you're struggling with?

Comment: If you are interested in discussing strategies and possibilities, then maybe this isn't the forum for you. You could check out https://discuss.ocaml.org/ but they still expect you to provide the code and ideas you tired

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only call the max function so many times(assignment requirement), I would start by modifying the max function so you can track how many times its called. Something like this:

```
let times = ref 0

let max a1 a2 =
  times := (!times) + 1;
  if a1 > a2
  then
    a1
  else
    a2

let () = print_endline (string_of_int (!times))
```

When you get a working solution, you can remove the counter from the max function.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate elements of the list and keep the biggest integers in the accumulator. The following function has **O(n)**. It returns **None** when the length of the list is less than two and **Some** result otherwise.

```ml
let double_max = 
  let rec f (a, b) = function
    | h :: t when h > a -> f (h, a) t
    | h :: t when h > b -> f (a, h) t
    | _ :: t            -> f (a, b) t
    | []                ->   (a, b) in
  function 
  | a :: b :: t when a > b 
                -> Some (f (a, b) t)
  | a :: b :: t -> Some (f (b, a) t)
  | _           -> None
```